# Clustering a Column with Similar Descriptions via Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk, cluster-analysis

I have a column in my dataset which has car accident descriptions. A lot of the descriptions are inconsistent but mean the same thing. For instance, if I consider the first 7 rows(my actual dataset is 17,000+ rows)of the variable labled `Descriptions`:

```
Descriptions
CLMT REAR ENDED IV
claimant REAR ENDED IV
CLM'R EAR ENDED IV
4 way stop sgn
CLM'T  rear-ended IV
IV STOPPED AT RED LIGHT WAS REAR ENDED BY CLM'T
IV Stopped at red light when IV was R/E by OV
```

where `CLMT REAR ENDED IV` and `claimant REAR ENDED IV` mean the same thing however they are spelled slightly differently. I would like to generate a variable that groups them into the same category. The end goal would be something like this:

```
Descriptions                                    clusterGroup
CLMT REAR ENDED IV                                cluster1
claimant REAR ENDED IV                            cluster1
CLM'R EAR ENDED IV                                cluster1
4 way stop sgn                                    cluster2
CLM'T  rear-ended IV                              cluster1
IV STOPPED AT RED LIGHT WAS REAR ENDED BY CLM'T   cluster3
IV Stopped at red light when IV was R/E by OV     cluster3
```

I know this is wrong, I'm not sure how to make each row a nltk sentence to then cluster using scikit learns kmean:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
import nltk

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
documents = df['Descriptions'].apply(nltk.sent_tokenize)    

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
true_k = 50
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
predict=model.predict(X)   
df['clusterGroup'] = Series(predict, index=X.index)
```

When I run the script above I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Considering that every row in the `Descriptions` pandas column is a sentence how could I potentially use nltk to break these off into to sentences that I could run a kmeans or some other clustering algorithm on? Any help or directional assistance would be appreciated

Comment: You can follow this tutorial: http://nlpforhackers.io/recipe-text-clustering/

Comment: Do you just want to cluster descriptions by similarity, regardless of topic, or do you have (or can make) a specific list of categories to which the descriptions should be assigned? If the second, look into classifiers.

Comment: My end goal is to produce something like what they did here https://github.com/smilli/clust but ideally with labels for each clusters. I'm not really trying to classify more so cluster into groups

Comment: The easy way to perform this task is with OpenRefine https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Clustering

Answer (score 0):

An unsupervised method like k-means will always perform poorly on this task.

Because it is all about *understanding language* and that is not going to happen just from this tiny segment of data. You can do impressive things with statistical analysis of language (see Google Assistant), but you **need billions of documents to train**. And even then, it likely involves a lot of labeled training data, too.

Comment: thank you for your reply, what would recommend I do? I would like to keep this variable, I think it could give us meaningful insight to our dataset

Comment: I don't have any recommendation, because I believe this *cannot* be automated at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to one of the links:

[roup-thousands-of-similar-spreadsheet-text-cells-in-seconds](https://towardsdatascience.com/group-thousands-of-similar-spreadsheet-text-cells-in-seconds-2493b3ce6d8d)

[clustering-product-names-with-python](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-product-names-with-python-part-2-648cc54ca2ac)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31140931)